# http post not sending out variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, vue.js

In my VUE application I am trying to send out a variable called c (c for color). For some reason all the other variables in my http post request are being sent correctly however for this.c the value sent is always blank. This is odd becuase when I print the value of this.c in the context of the function I am making the request from the value of this.c is correct (in that it is the same value entered by the user into the select tag). And yet even though the value is correct when I make the post the value for the color1 property is always blank. (Again all the other properties in the post make their way to the server fine except for color1)

Here is the relevant code:

```
<template>
   <div id="calendar"  :navL="navLinks" :event-sources="eventSources" @event-selected="eventSelected" @event-created="eventCreated"  :config="config" >
      <div class="container" id="calendarContainer">
         <div id="end">
            <div class="col-2">
               <select v-model="c">
                  <option value="#07889B">Blue</option>
                  <option value="#F9CF00">Yellow</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <full-calendar id="target" ref="calendar" :event-sources="eventSources" @event-selected="eventSelected" @day-click="click"@event-created="eventCreated" :config="config"></full-calendar>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
   import moment from 'moment';
   const self = this;
   export default {
      name: 'calendar',
      data() {
         return {
            //there are other variables in here of course
            c: "color", //************ this variable wont get sent in post request    
         };
      },
      methods: {
         submit: function() {
            console.log(this.c); //*****************
            this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/operation?Stime='+this.Stime+'&Etime='+this.Etime+'&eAMPM='+this.eAMPM+'&sAMPM='+this.sAMPM+'&id='+this.id+'&activity='+this.activity+'&auto_insert='+this.auto_insert+'&yearmonthday='+this.yearmonthday+'&color1='+this.c)
         },
      },
   }
</script>
```

Comment: `...'&color1='+this.c+'')`

Comment: that did not work

Comment: does sending it first work?

Comment: Well, you're post body is empty, all the variables are being sent on the querystring (as if you were doing a GET).  And the color variable has a # in it, and you know what *that* does to urls.  So either urlencode all your variables or actually use the post body to send them.

Comment: thanks James I was not paying attention to the # that solved my problem